# How to understand rdispls (recv_displacement) quantity in MPI_Alltoallv

Tags: python, numpy, mpi

As titled, I think it should be a cumulated quantity from `recv_count`. So for the `i` process, the received data are inserted to the location `recv_data + rdispls(i)*extent(recv_type)`. To make this clear, I try to rewrite the example in Python. It gives a wrong answer due to the wrong `recv_disp` (maybe as well the `send_disp`):

Example: https://rookiehpc.org/mpi/docs/mpi_alltoallv/index.html

My attempt in Python: (here I did not change the order `recv_data` in process 0 as that in the example)

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

assert size == 3

# Send data
if rank == 0:
    send_data = np.array([0, 100, 200],   dtype=np.int32)
    send_rank = np.array([0, 1,   1],     dtype=np.int32)
elif rank == 1:
    send_data = np.array([300, 400, 500], dtype=np.int32)
    send_rank = np.array([2,   2,   2],   dtype=np.int32)
else:
    send_data = np.array([600],           dtype=np.int32)
    send_rank = np.array([0],             dtype=np.int32)

send_length = len(send_data)
send_counts = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
for procs_id in send_rank:
    send_counts[procs_id] += 1

send_disp     = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
send_disp[1:] = np.cumsum(send_counts)[:-1]

# Receive data
recv_counts = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
comm.Alltoall(send_counts, recv_counts)
recv_length = np.sum(recv_counts)
recv_data = np.zeros(recv_length, dtype=np.int32)
recv_disp = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
recv_disp[1:] = np.cumsum(recv_counts)[:-1]         # Comment this and get correct answer

# Alltoallv
comm.Alltoallv([send_data, send_counts, recv_disp, MPI.INT],
               [recv_data, recv_counts, recv_disp, MPI.INT])

print(f"rank:\n{rank}\n"
      f"send_counts:\n{send_counts}\n"
      f"recv_counts:\n{recv_counts}\n"
      f"send_disp:\n{send_disp}\n"
      f"recv_disp:\n{recv_disp}\n"
      f"send_data:\n{send_data}\n"
      f"recv_data:\n{recv_data}\n"
      f"recv_length:\n{recv_length}\n"
      )
```

Comment: please explain the difference between the actual values vs the values you expect.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet For process 2, the `recv_data` should return 
[300 400 500], while the Python code gives me [500 22053 1532713789]. I've checked that my evaluated `recv_disp` is different with the manually set values in that URL example. So I think I misunderstand the meaning of displacement.

Comment: OK, I found the mistake is due to a typo in ```comm.Alltoallv([send_data, send_counts, recv_disp, MPI.INT], [recv_data, recv_counts, recv_disp, MPI.INT])```, where two `recv_disp` are used...